# Performance issue uploading even small files to Azure Blob Storage in .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

We are using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library to upload files in .net7 environment. Some requests take 100 second which is default `HttpClient` timeout i think. I've read about blob storage client api uses a shared `HttpClient` object and it says that is thread safe but the const 100 second makes me thinking there is a bottleneck about HttpClient inside the library. I am confused at this point.

In our business, we have almost 20 containers in azure blob storage and the request comes with the container and blob name. Therefore I need to get the BlobContainerClient and BlobClient Objects in every request. This is the part that I'm suspicious. According to New Relic metrics, I understand that getting BlobContainerClient object takes 100 second ["packing" is one of our containers name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9UoV.png). It seems this is waiting a connection to finish I don't know.

This is our upload file method.

```
public async Task<string> UploadFileFromByteArrayAsync(string containerName, string blobName, byte[] fileBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    BlobClient blob = await GetBlobInstance(containerName, blobName, true);

    await blob.UploadAsync(new BinaryData(fileBytes), overwrite:true, cancellationToken);

    return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}


private async Task<BlobClient> GetBlobInstance(string containerName, string blobName, bool crateIfNotExist = false)
{
    BlobContainerClient container = await GetContainerInstance(containerName, crateIfNotExist);

    BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    return blob;
}

private async Task<BlobContainerClient> GetContainerInstance(string containerName, bool crateIfNotExist = false)
{
    BlobContainerClient container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

    if (crateIfNotExist)
    {
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
    }

    return container;
}
```

And I've created a singleton lifetime for BlobServiceClient which is recommended.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ =>
{
    return new BlobServiceClient(builder.Configuration.GetSection("azureStorageConfiguration").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString"));
});
```

Note * all uploading files size are small like 15-20 Kib.

Answer (score 0):

> According to New Relic metrics, I understand that getting
> BlobContainerClient object takes 100 second "packing" is one of our
> containers name. It seems this is waiting a connection to finish I
> don't know.

I believe this is the problem. I noticed that you are passing `true` for `crateIfNotExist` parameter and what your code end up doing is trying to create the blob container on every request to upload blob.

If you know that your containers are going to be present in the storage account, you can pass `false` for `crateIfNotExist` parameter and that should speed up the uploading process.

In short, try to change the following line of code:

```
BlobClient blob = await GetBlobInstance(containerName, blobName, true);
```

to

```
BlobClient blob = await GetBlobInstance(containerName, blobName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. This might be the case really, i have not tested on production yet but tested on dev, the slowness of ...blob.com/{containername} PUT request gone from new relic metrics. But some requests still look slow uploading requestlike ...blob.com/{containerName}/{blobName} it takes %90 percantage of total time (250ms) to uploada 15-20 KiB File. Do you think creating a BlobContainerClient object every request might cause that ? creating static or singleton BlobContainerClient object might be better ?  @Gaurav Mantri

Comment: `Do you think creating a BlobContainerClient object every request might cause that ? creating static or singleton BlobContainerClient object might be better ?` - No, it will not make any difference.

Comment: Hello again, we could finally released the change but unfortunatelly 100 sec issue continue. But this time, the url I shared in the picture(...blob.com/{containername} PUT) is gone but GET request took 100 sec now. 
 https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net:443/label/account/39569e1b-f5c3-4a63-8e62-fafa39252b20/shipmentorder/14d55961-20fb-4027-9c45-3c4e56680af0/Merged_20230721062220.pdf STREAM/GET. Do you have any more suggestion

Comment: I still suspect somehow new requests are waiting for previous connectionss to release. It seems something blocks the connection and waits 100 second. @gaurav-mantri

Comment: I think there's something else. 100 seconds to read a blob is too much (I'm assuming the blob size is not that big). You may want to write a simple console app and just try to read the blob there and check the result. Or access the blob in the browser and notice the time it takes for the request.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not happen everytime. Some requests appear in new relic. Accessing the blob and files from browser is not an issue, i can do that easily. It might be a code side issue

Comment: Hello again, @GauravMantri, this picture [link](https://prnt.sc/xN5YVXkm66Rm) shows uploading a small file takes 100 seconds then it uploads same file after 100 seconds and it takes 200-300ms. We are using Azure.Storage.Blob library, is just retrying itsel to upload because I have not set any configuration for that.